# C++17 Either implementation for error handling

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++17, monads, variant-type

This is a C++17 Either implementation for error handling.

- First intent is I want to improve myself.
- Second intent is I want to create a more expressive solution than variant for exception free error handling.
- Third intent is same type handling without extra variable.

**to_left(...)** and **to_right(...)** helper functions for specified side if both types are same in **Result**.

**Left** and **Right** are helper structs for avoid additional bool usage in **Result**.

**result.hpp**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

namespace marklar::result
{
// Helper
template<typename Type>
struct Left;

template<typename Type>
struct Right;

template<typename>
struct is_left : std::false_type {};

template<typename Type>
struct is_left<Left<Type>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename Type>
inline constexpr bool is_left_v = is_left<Type>::value;

template<typename>
struct is_right : std::false_type {};

template<typename Type>
struct is_right<Right<Type>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename Type>
inline constexpr bool is_right_v = is_right<Type>::value;

template<typename Type>
inline constexpr Left<Type>
to_left(Type const & value) {
    return Left<Type>{ value };
}

template<typename Type, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_move_constructible_v<Type>, bool> = true>
inline constexpr Left<Type>
to_left(Type && value) {
    return Left<Type>{ std::forward<Type>(value) };
}

template<typename Type>
inline constexpr Right<Type>
to_right(Type const & value) {
    return Right<Type>{ value };
}

template<typename Type, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_move_constructible_v<Type>, bool> = true>
inline constexpr Right<Type>
to_right(Type && value) {
    return Right<Type>{ std::forward<Type>(value) };
}

template<typename Type>
struct Left {
    Type const value_;

    template <typename ParamType = Type,
              typename std::enable_if_t<
                 !std::is_same_v<Left<Type>, ParamType>
                 && std::is_constructible_v<Type, ParamType &&>
                 && std::is_convertible_v<ParamType &&, Type>
                 , bool> = true>
    constexpr Left(ParamType && value)
        : value_ { std::forward<ParamType>(value) }
    {}

    template <typename ParamType = Type,
              typename std::enable_if_t<
                 !std::is_same_v<Left<Type>, ParamType>
                 && std::is_constructible_v<Type, ParamType &&>
                 && !std::is_convertible_v<ParamType &&, Type>
                 , bool> = false>
    constexpr explicit Left(ParamType && value)
        : value_ { std::forward<ParamType>(value) }
    {}

    template <typename ParamType = Type,
              typename std::enable_if_t<
                 !std::is_same_v<Type, ParamType>
                     && std::is_constructible_v<Type, ParamType const &>
                     && !std::is_convertible_v<ParamType const &, Type>
                 , bool> = false>
    explicit constexpr Left(Left<ParamType> const & other)
        : value_ { other.value_ }
    {}

    template <typename ParamType = Type,
              typename std::enable_if_t<
                 !std::is_same_v<Type, ParamType>
                 && std::is_constructible_v<Type, ParamType &&>
                 && std::is_convertible_v<ParamType &&, Type>
                 , bool> = true>
    constexpr Left(Left<ParamType> && other)
        : value_ { std::move(other).value_ }
    {}

    template <typename ParamType = Type,
              typename std::enable_if_t<
                 !std::is_same_v<Type, ParamType>
                 && std::is_constructible_v<Type, ParamType &&>
                 && !std::is_convertible_v<ParamType &&, Type>
                 , bool> = false>
    explicit constexpr Left(Left<ParamType> && other)
        : value_ { std::move(other).value_ }
    {}
};

template<typename Type>
struct Right {
    Type const value_;

    template <typename ParamType = Type,
              typename std::enable_if_t<
                 !std::is_same_v<Right<Type>, ParamType>
                 && std::is_constructible_v<Type, ParamType &&>
                 && std::is_convertible_v<ParamType &&, Type>
                 , bool> = true>
    constexpr Right(ParamType && value)
        : value_ { std::forward<ParamType>(value) }
    {}

    template <typename ParamType = Type,
              typename std::enable_if_t<
                 !std::is_same_v<Right<Type>, ParamType>
                 && std::is_constructible_v<Type, ParamType &&>
                 && !std::is_convertible_v<ParamType &&, Type>
                 , bool> = false>
    constexpr explicit Right(ParamType && value)
        : value_ { std::forward<ParamType>(value) }
    {}

    template <typename ParamType = Type,
              typename std::enable_if_t<
                 !std::is_same_v<Type, ParamType>
                 && std::is_constructible_v<Type, ParamType const &>
                 && !std::is_convertible_v<ParamType const &, Type>
                 , bool> = false>
    explicit constexpr Right(Right<ParamType> const & other)
        : value_ { other.value_ }
    {}

    template <typename ParamType = Type,
              typename std::enable_if_t<
                 !std::is_same_v<Type, ParamType>
                 && std::is_constructible_v<Type, ParamType &&>
                 && std::is_convertible_v<ParamType &&, Type>
                 , bool> = true>
    constexpr Right(Right<ParamType> && other)
        : value_ { std::move(other).value_ }
    {}

    template <typename ParamType = Type,
              typename std::enable_if_t<
                 !std::is_same_v<Type, ParamType>
                 && std::is_constructible_v<Type, ParamType &&>
                 && !std::is_convertible_v<ParamType &&, Type>
                 , bool> = false>
    explicit constexpr Right(Right<ParamType> && other)
        : value_ { std::move(other).value_ }
    {}
};

template<typename LeftType, typename RightType>
struct Result {
    static_assert(!(std::is_reference_v<LeftType> || std::is_reference_v<RightType>)
                      , "Result must have no reference alternative");
    static_assert(!(std::is_void_v<LeftType> || std::is_void_v<RightType>)
                      , "Result must have no void alternative");

    using LeftValue = Left<LeftType>;
    using RightValue = Right<RightType>;

    static constexpr size_t index_left_ = 0;
    static constexpr size_t index_right_ = 1;

    const std::variant<const LeftValue, const RightValue> variant_;

    constexpr explicit Result(Result<LeftType, RightType> && other)
        : variant_ { std::forward<Result<LeftType, RightType>>( other ).variant_ }
    {}

    template<typename ParamType>
    constexpr explicit Result(ParamType const & value)
        : variant_ {
            []() -> auto {
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<LeftType, ParamType> || is_left_v<ParamType>) {
                    return std::in_place_index<index_left_>;
                } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RightType, ParamType> || is_right_v<ParamType>) {
                    return std::in_place_index<index_right_>;
                }
            }()
            , [](ParamType const & value) -> auto {
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<LeftType, ParamType>) {
                    return to_left(value);
                } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RightType, ParamType>) {
                    return to_right(value);
                } else if constexpr (is_left_v<ParamType> || is_right_v<ParamType>) {
                    return value;
                }
            }(value)
        }
    {
        static_assert((is_left_v<ParamType> || is_right_v<ParamType> || std::is_same_v<LeftType, ParamType> || std::is_same_v<RightType, ParamType>)
                      , "Result only setted alternatives can use");

        if constexpr (!(is_left_v<ParamType> || is_right_v<ParamType>)) {
            static_assert(!std::is_same_v<LeftType, RightType>
                          , "Result must have distinguish between alternatives");
        }
    }

    template<typename ParamType>
    constexpr explicit Result(ParamType && value) noexcept
        : variant_ {
            []() -> auto {
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<LeftType, ParamType> || is_left_v<ParamType>) {
                    return std::in_place_index<index_left_>;
                } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RightType, ParamType> || is_right_v<ParamType>) {
                    return std::in_place_index<index_right_>;
                }
            }()
            , [](ParamType && value) -> auto {
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<LeftType, ParamType>) {
                    return to_left(std::forward<ParamType>(value));
                } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RightType, ParamType>) {
                    return to_right(std::forward<ParamType>(value));
                } else if constexpr (is_left_v<ParamType> || is_right_v<ParamType>) {
                    return std::forward<ParamType>(value);
                }
            }(std::forward<ParamType>(value))
        }
    {
        static_assert((is_left_v<ParamType> || is_right_v<ParamType> || std::is_same_v<LeftType, ParamType> || std::is_same_v<RightType, ParamType>)
                          , "Result only setted alternatives can use");

        if constexpr (!(is_left_v<ParamType> || is_right_v<ParamType>)) {
            static_assert(!std::is_same_v<LeftType, RightType>
                          , "Result must have distinguish between alternatives");
        }
    }

    template<typename TempType = LeftType>
    inline constexpr TempType const &
    left() const &
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<TempType, LeftType>);

        return std::get<index_left_>(variant_).value_;
    }

    template<typename TempType = LeftType>
    constexpr TempType &&
    left() &&
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<TempType &&, LeftType>);

        return std::move(std::get<index_left_>(variant_).value_);
    }

    template<typename TempType = LeftType>
    constexpr LeftType
    left_or(TempType && substitute) const &
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<TempType &&, LeftType>);

        return std::holds_alternative<const LeftValue>(variant_)
                   ? this->left()
                   : static_cast<LeftType>(std::forward<TempType>(substitute));
    }

    template<typename TempType = LeftType>
    constexpr LeftType &&
    left_or(TempType && substitute) &&
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<TempType &&, LeftType>);

        return std::holds_alternative<const LeftValue>(variant_)
                   ? std::move(this->left())
                   : static_cast<LeftType>(std::forward<TempType>(substitute));
    }

    template<typename TempType = RightType>
    inline constexpr TempType const &
    right() const &
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<TempType, RightType>);

        return std::get<index_right_>(variant_).value_;
    }

    template<typename TempType = RightType>
    constexpr TempType &&
    right() &&
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<TempType &&, RightType>);

        return std::move(std::get<index_right_>(variant_).value_);
    }

    template<typename TempType = RightType>
    constexpr RightType
    right_or(TempType && substitute) const &
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<TempType &&, RightType>);

        return std::holds_alternative<const LeftValue>(variant_)
                   ? static_cast<RightType>(std::forward<TempType>(substitute))
                   : this->right();
    }

    template<typename TempType = RightType>
    constexpr RightType &&
    right_or(TempType && substitute) &&
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<TempType &&, RightType>);

        return std::holds_alternative<const LeftValue>(variant_)
                   ? static_cast<RightType>(std::forward<TempType>(substitute))
                   : std::move(this->right());
    }

    template<typename Function>
    inline constexpr auto left_map(Function const & function) &&
        -> Result<decltype(function(std::get<index_left_>(variant_).value_)), RightType>
    {
        return std::holds_alternative<const LeftValue>(variant_)
                   ? Result{ to_left(function(this->left())) }
                   : Result{ std::get<index_right_>(variant_) };
    }

    template<typename Function>
    inline constexpr auto
    right_map(Function const & function) const
        -> Result<LeftType, decltype(function(std::get<index_right_>(variant_).value_))>
    {
        return std::holds_alternative<const LeftValue>(variant_)
                   ? Result{ std::get<index_left_>(variant_) }
                   : Result{ to_right(function(this->right())) };
    }

    template<typename LeftLocal = LeftType, typename RightLocal = RightType>
    inline constexpr auto
    join() const
        -> std::common_type_t<const LeftLocal, const RightLocal>
    {
        return std::holds_alternative<const LeftValue>(variant_)
                   ? this->left()
                   : this->right();
    }

    inline constexpr operator bool() const noexcept
    {
        return std::holds_alternative<const LeftValue>(variant_);
    }
};
} // namespace marklar::result
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "result.hpp"

// Tester function
auto tester(int result) {
    using R = marklar::result::Result<int, std::string>;

    return
        (result < 0)
            ? R( marklar::result::to_right<std::string>("It is a negative number") )
            : R( marklar::result::to_left<int>(result) )
    ;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << "Positive test\n";
    auto resOk = tester(42);
    if(resOk) {
        std::cout << "data : " << std::to_string(resOk.left()) << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "error : " << resOk.right() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::cout << "Negative test\n";
    auto resErr = tester(-1);
    if(resErr) {
        std::cout << "data : " << std::to_string(resErr.left()) << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "error : " << resErr.right() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Same type test - lef side\n";
    marklar::result::Result<int, int> resSameLeft(marklar::result::to_left(42));
    std::cout << "Is store left data? : " << static_cast<bool>(resSameLeft) << "\n";
    std::cout << "data : " << std::to_string(resSameLeft.left()) << "\n";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Same type test - right side\n";
    marklar::result::Result<int, int> resSameRight(marklar::result::to_right(24));
    std::cout << "Is store left data? : " << static_cast<bool>(resSameRight) << "\n";
    std::cout << "data : " << std::to_string(resSameRight.right()) << "\n";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[An working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e762691bfbaf227)

**My questions:**

- Any suggestion for better implementation?
- Is the perfect forwarding correctly used?
- Can be improve the usability?

Comment: Title says “Result”, question body says “Either”, which is it? And what is it supposed to do? A usage example would be useful, ideally in a `main` so we can run your code without making changes. You are also missing `#include` statements.

Comment: You code seems good, but what is the intent? In particular, what's wrong with `variant`? What's wrong with exceptions?

Comment: - First intent is I want to improve myself.
- Second intent is I want to create a more expressive solution than variant for exception free error handling.
- Third intent is same type handling without extra variable.

Comment: You could significantly improve usability by foregoing a new type for `Result`, and making `Left` and `Right` more widely applicable. Simply use `std::variant` directly, and add a template encoding a statically chosen option from a `std::variant`. Perhaps a few convenience aliases and/or functions, and you are done.

Comment: Why do you think it is improve the usability? Thanks

Comment: He's asking about the intent of the code, not your intent (although that's important too, but it's already mentioned at the top of the question). What is the code supposed to do and does it do so to your satisfaction or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you go a very long and very complicated way to do exactly what `std::variant` does; since you're tagging your question with `reinvent-the-wheel` it could be perfectly legitimate, but then you can't use `std::variant` inside your code, because you can't use a wheel to reinvent it.

What is the `Either` monad? It's not necessarily about error handling, even if it indeed is often used as beefed-up version of `Maybe`. It only is a type that can hold one of two arbitrary types. Generalizing it into a `AnyTypeOf` monad, it would become a type that can hold one of several arbitrary types. That is to say, a `std::variant`. At least conceptually, you rely on a more powerful type (`std::variant`) to implement a less powerful one (`Either`) and need 350 lines of very complex code to do it.

Here's my version of the `Either` monad:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
using Either = std::variant<T, U>;
```

I confess that it is a bit rudimentary, but it isn't very difficult to derive the whole monadic interface from it. But let's precise the semantics a bit, since we're looking for exception-free error handling:

```
template <typename T>
using SafeType = Either<std::string, T>;
```

Note that the convention is for the right type to hold the correct value, and the left type the error. Now we can write simple constructors-like functions:

```
using SafeInteger = Either<std::string, int>; /

SafeInteger left(std::string error_message) { return SafeInteger(error_message); }
SafeInteger right(int i)                    { return SafeInteger(i); }
```

If the type of the error message and of the value are the same, it's just a few characters longer:

```
using SafeString = Either<std::string, std::string>;

SafeString left(std::string error_message) { return SafeString(std::in_place_index_t<0>(), error_message); }
SafeString right(std::string str)          { return SafeString(std::in_place_index_t<1>(), std::move(str)); }
```

The monadic scaffolding is also just a few lines long (I implemented it around `return` and `bind`, but `join` wouldn't have been more complex):

```
auto monadic_return(std::string str) {
    return right(str);
}

template <typename Function>
auto monadic_bind(const SafeString& str, Function func) {
    if (std::get_if<0>(&str)) return str;
    return func(std::get<1>(str));
}
```

Complete example here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Sj61MC1jbEO20T5B

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, the solution is somewhere bloated. I tried to put everything to a class/struct. In your solution always right side is the intended result. I tried also this part to generalize, but after rethink this was unnecessary.

Comment: Of course, `std::string` can throw an exception on assignment / initialisation, which might throw a spanner in the works of that example.

Comment: @Deduplicator: a spanner? / right, it'd be more sensible to allocate a buffer on the stack but I feel lazy.